# Array object in java

Tags: java, arrays, vector

Im new at Object-Oriented Programming, I need to make a code that reads a list of N nonzero numbers and store it in a vector. After filling, it should print data read.

This is the code

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 

class Programa1Vectores_Objetos{ 
    int n,nal; 
    int Vector[]= new int[n]; 

    void setvector(int xvector[]){ 
        Random Aleatorio =new Random(); 
        int nal;    
        for(int i=0; i<xvector.length; i++){ 
            nal=Aleatorio.nextInt(10); 
            if (nal==0){ 
                i--; 
                continue; 
            } 
            xvector[i]=nal; 
        } 
    } 

    int getvector(){ 
        return Vector[n]; 
    } 
} 

class EjecutaPrograma1{ 
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException { 
        int n=0; 
        int Vector[]= new int[n]; 

        Programa1Vectores_Objetos Programa1 = new Programa1Vectores_Objetos();  
        n=Lectura_NumeroVector(""); 
        Programa1.setvector(Vector); 
        Programa1.getvector(); 
    } 

    public static int Lectura_NumeroVector (String TxtMsg) throws java.io.IOException{ 
        int X=0; 
        String teclado; 
        DataInputStream cadena= new DataInputStream(System.in); 

        do{ 
            System.out.print("Longitud del Vector: "); 
            teclado=cadena.readLine(); 
            try{ 
                X=Integer.parseInt(teclado); 
                if(X<1){ 
                    System.out.println("Tienes que escribir un numero mayor a cero"); 
                    continue; 
                } 
            return X; 
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){ 
                System.out.println("Escribe un numero");    
            } 
        }while(true); 
    } 
}
```

When im trying to run and I give the number of the length of the vector it it appears something like

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
  at Programa1Vectores_Objetos.getVector(Programa1Vectores_Objetos.java:25)
  at EjecutaPrograma1.main(Programa1Vectores_Objetos.java:47)
```

Line 25

```
int getvector(){
    return Vector[n]; //Line 25
}
```

Line 47

```
Programa1.getvector();
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks!

Comment: your code doesn't even compile

Comment: One problem is, that class EjecutaPrograma1 should be public.

Comment: Prototype of `getvector` should be `int[] getVector()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize Vector with size 0 in your main method. You never set it to the new size, try moving the initialization of your vector down after setting n like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException { 
    int n=0; 
    // int Vector[]= new int[n]; 
    Programa1Vectores_Objetos Programa1 = new Programa1Vectores_Objetos();  
    n=Lectura_NumeroVector(""); 
    int Vector[]= new int[n]; // n isn't 0 anymore
    Programa1.setvector(Vector); 
    Programa1.getvector(); 
}
```

Then in setVector, you never set the Vector variable, I believe at the end of setvector you should do `Vector = xvector`, so it should look like this:

```
void setvector(int xvector[]){ 
    Random Aleatorio =new Random(); 
    int nal;    
    for(int i=0; i<xvector.length; i++){ 
        nal=Aleatorio.nextInt(10); 
        if (nal==0){ 
            i--; 
            continue; 
        } 
        xvector[i]=nal; 
    } 
    Vector = xvector;   // Vector needs to be set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well for a start

```
int n=0; 
int Vector[]= new int[n];
```

this code is going to create an array of nothing.  Try using a bigger number.

A probably better way to use a List e.g. [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

If you had actually debugged your code you would have found this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Since at the start you does not seem to know how many input values you will have, you should go for a `List` instead of an array. It has the advantage of automatically growing with your input data. So use

```
List<Integer> Vector = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

You need to change some of your additional code, because e.g. access to the members of a list is syntactically different from accessing an array `Vector[i]` becomes `Vector.get(i)`.